# UITextfield and UIButton not clicking inside UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have a few textfield and button inside a UIView but the click event is not getting called I have checked the Height of the UIView its more than my button and textview. As you can see in the screenshot of UIView:
[Frame of UIView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7mSN.png)
These are the screenshot of TextField and button
[This is the first Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2laZ.png)

[And this is the last button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKRDP.png)

And in between there are lots of labels and textfield. As you can see in this image 
    [This is the image of my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHiey.jpg)

Also I have set

```
userInteractionEnabled=NO
```

for the UIView and

```
userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

for the TextField and Button but still no luck. I have no clue what to do next.This is my code

```
- (void)addChemicalTapped:(UIButton *)sender {

    _ans6Constraint.constant = 750;
//    [self.addChemical addTarget:self action:@selector(fixDelaysContentTouches:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleTextBeginEditing:) name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:_Ans6Text1new1];

    _chemicalUIview.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
//    _chemical1scroll.userInteractionEnabled=false;
    _Ans6Text4new1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    _Ans6Text2new1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    _Ans6Text1new1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    _Ans6Text3new1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [_RemoveChemical1 setTag:1234];
    [_RemoveChemical1 addTarget:self action:@selector(RemoveChemical1Tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [self reloadTable];
}
```

There is no problem with click event because the id of same textfield and button is getting called in different UIView. So there is some thing wrong with my UIView code. This is my UIView code

```
UIView *paddingView3 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
    [_ans6Text1 setClipsToBounds:NO];
    [_ans6Text1.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [_ans6Text1.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    [_ans6Text1.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
    [_ans6Text1 setLeftView:paddingView3];
    [_ans6Text1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
        UIView *paddingView3new1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [_Ans6Text1new1 setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_Ans6Text1new1.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_Ans6Text1new1.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_Ans6Text1new1.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_Ans6Text1new1 setLeftView:paddingView3new1];
        [_Ans6Text1new1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];

    UIView *paddingView4 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
    [_ans6Text2 setClipsToBounds:NO];
    [_ans6Text2.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [_ans6Text2.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    [_ans6Text2.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
    [_ans6Text2 setLeftView:paddingView4];
    [_ans6Text2 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
    [_ans6Text2 setInputView:_datePicker];
        UIView *paddingView4new1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [_Ans6Text2new1 setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_Ans6Text2new1.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_Ans6Text2new1.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_Ans6Text2new1.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_Ans6Text2new1 setLeftView:paddingView4new1];
        [_Ans6Text2new1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
        [_Ans6Text2new1 setInputView:_datePicker];

    UIView *paddingView5 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
    [_ans6Text3 setClipsToBounds:NO];
    [_ans6Text3.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [_ans6Text3.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    [_ans6Text3.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
    [_ans6Text3 setLeftView:paddingView5];
    [_ans6Text3 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
        UIView *paddingView5new1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [_Ans6Text3new1 setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_Ans6Text3new1.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_Ans6Text3new1.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_Ans6Text3new1.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_Ans6Text3new1 setLeftView:paddingView5new1];
        [_Ans6Text3new1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];

    UIView *paddingView6 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
    [_ans6Text4 setClipsToBounds:NO];
    [_ans6Text4.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [_ans6Text4.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    [_ans6Text4.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
    [_ans6Text4 setLeftView:paddingView6];
    [_ans6Text4 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
        UIView *paddingView6new1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [_Ans6Text4new1 setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_Ans6Text4new1.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_Ans6Text4new1.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_Ans6Text4new1.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_Ans6Text4new1 setLeftView:paddingView6new1];
        [_Ans6Text4new1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
```

Ans6Text1new1,Ans6Text2new1,Ans6Text3new1 and Ans6Text4new1 are the textfields which are not getting selected.
This is code for second textfield where we get the date.

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *selectedDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[self.datePicker date]];
    NSString *pastDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[self.datePickerPast date]];

    if ([textField isEqual:_ans6Text2]) {
        [self.ans6Text2 setText:selectedDate];
        [self.ans6Text2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.ans6Text2 setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:5.0/255.0 green:85.0/255.0 blue:160.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    }
    if ([textField isEqual:_Ans6Text2new1]) {
        [self.Ans6Text2new1 setText:selectedDate];
        [self.Ans6Text2new1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.Ans6Text2new1 setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:5.0/255.0 green:85.0/255.0 blue:160.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    }

    else if ([textField isEqual:_ans4Text2]) {
        [self.ans4Text2 setText:pastDate];
        [self.ans4Text2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.ans4Text2 setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:5.0/255.0 green:85.0/255.0 blue:160.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    }
    else if ([textField isEqual:_ans7Text2]) {
        [self.ans7Text2 setText:pastDate];
        [self.ans7Text2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.ans7Text2 setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:5.0/255.0 green:85.0/255.0 blue:160.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    }
    else if ([textField isEqual:_ans7Text4]) {
        [self.ans7Text4 setText:pastDate];
        [self.ans7Text4 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.ans7Text4 setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:5.0/255.0 green:85.0/255.0 blue:160.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    }
    else if ([textField isEqual:_ans7Text5]) {
        [self.ans7Text5 setText:pastDate];
        [self.ans7Text5 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.ans7Text5 setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:5.0/255.0 green:85.0/255.0 blue:160.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    }
    else if ([textField isEqual:_ans8Text1]) {
        [self.ans8Text1 setText:pastDate];
        [self.ans8Text1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.ans8Text1 setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:5.0/255.0 green:85.0/255.0 blue:160.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    }
}
```

Ans6Text2new1 is the textfield which is not getting clicked. The screenshot of my Layout is below
[The UIView is marked in Red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmSvF.png). There are two UIView. In first UIView all the TextField and button is working and in the second UIView which is inside First UIView there no Button or textfield is working. This is the code for my Button click in UIView which is also not working

```
- (void)add1ChemicalTapped:(UIButton *)sender {

   NSLog(@"ADDnew tapped");
}
```

And in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    @try{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(self.isReceived==true){
        [_HSSwitch setEnabled:NO];
    }


        [_Add1Chemical addTarget:self action:@selector(add1ChemicalTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Comment: Setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` will render its children's input events to be disabled. So don't do that.

Comment: @RyanB I have set  userInteractionEnabled as YES still it is not getting clicked.

Comment: So what is the other code of your `UIView` container? Just a portion of code for a button's action will make it very hard to know what is happened.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Still the same as your other question. What & how is your `_chemicalUIview` be initialized. You said `_Ans6Text1new1` is added dynamically, but how & where did you do that?

Comment: I have initialised _chemicalUIview and  _Ans6Text1new1 through the designer not programatically.

Comment: I have put the screenshot of height and width of UIView and _Ans6Text1new1 in my question.

Comment: _chemicalUIview is the screenshot **Frame of UIView** and _Ans6Text1new1 is the screenshot **This is the first Label**

Comment: So, all of your `TextField` are put inside a `UIScrollView` & you did all the placement & positioning with Designer?

Comment: All my textfield and button is inside UIView which is inside another UIView. I'll put the screenshot of Layout for better understanding.

Comment: @RyanB I have put the screenshot **The UIView is marked in Red** at the end also I have explained how my Textfield is set inside the UIView.

Comment: @RyanB all the placement & positioning of Textfield and button is done with Designer.

Comment: I'd just made a sample project with the same view setup as you & to be honest, I find no difficult to make  it work without any issue like you. Did you just accidentally tap on the `UITextField`'s leftView instead?

Comment: No I didn't Tap on UITextField's leftView. And also why the buttons are not clicked.

Comment: I have added the code for that too at the end.

Comment: - First, remove @try/@catch, at least don't use it for development phase. 
- Use `IBAction` for `_Add1Chemical` or any other button. They are not dynamically created, so don't set their input events programmatically.
- Remove all `userInteractionEnabled` instructions as they will render children input to be disabled
- Also remove all `setClipsToBounds:NO` or make it become `YES`. They might as well make your UI bugs become harder to detect

Comment: IBAction for Add1Chemical and RemoveChemical1 . Also I have set setClipsToBounds:YES everywhere. And Removed all userInteractionEnabled from the code. But still it's not working.

Comment: @RyanB Is there any thing  wrong with UIView Frame because I've put the id of textfield of the second UIView on the first UIView and there the click function is already working so the data selected there is set in textview in Second UIView. I think there is something problem with Layout.

Comment: How can I detect the bug with Layout in IOS?

Answer (score 0):

no need to call

```
userInteractionEnabled=NO
```

because if you call this for Parent UIView then it disable user interaction for child views as well.